# Pass window variable as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

Passing a window global variable through JS does not seem to be working. The following code is printing true:

```js
window.nada = true;
tata(window.nada);
console.log(window.nada);

function tata(lala) {
  lala = false;
}
```

How can I affect the `window.nada` **global variable** inside the `tata` function?

Comment: You will have to reference the window object inside tada or pass the window object into tada.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, JavaScript uses [call-by-sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/14637).

In practice, you'll have to pass the entire `window` object, as well as the name of the property you want to change:

```
tata(window, 'nada');

function tata(window, prop)
{
  window[prop] = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `window.nada` is a primitive data type (`Boolean`).

Primitive data types are passed to the function per value and not per reference. So inside your `tata` function the `lala` variable does not know anything about the `window.nada` value

Comment: Even if it were an object; simply assigning to `lala` won't change anything in the `window` object. It just changes `lala` to refer to a different object.